# compare date on PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, sysdate

I have to create trigger that raises an error if I try to delete from table and the date on the table is equal with `sysdate`.

This is my code:

```
create or replace trigger nonViolation
  before insert or delete on reservation
  for each row
declare 
  error exception;
  error2 exception;
  dateres date:=sysdate;
begin
  if inserting then
     if :new.dateDep<dateres then 
         raise error;
     end if;
  end if;

  if deleting then
     if (:OLD.datedep=dateres)
     then 
        raise error2;
     end if;
  end if;

exception
  when error2 then
    raise_application_error(-20003,'supression impossible');
  when error then 
    raise_application_error(-20001,'reservation impossible');
end;
```

I tried to delete a row that contain today's`date 25-nov-18`and the trigger doesn't work. I tried to print the values of `:old.datedep` and `dateres` and they are the same:

```
25-nov-2018
25-nov-2018
```

Can someone help me? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're not allowing for the fact that SYSDATE contains the current time as well as the current date. Perhaps your trigger will produce the desired outcome if you remove the time element like this:

```
    ...
    error2 exception;
    dateres date := trunc(sysdate);
begin
    ...
```

> "it doesn't work ,"

As @bobjarvis suggests you may need to strip the time element from `datedep` (depending on how you populate it):

```
if TRUNC(:OLD.datedep) = dateres
```

Try using a complete date format mask such as `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'` and see what you actually have.

Comment: Also need to change `if (:OLD.datedep=dateres)` to `if TRUNC(:OLD.datedep) = dateres`.

Comment: it doesn't work , anyway when i tried to get the value of dateres I get 25-nov-2018 without time

Comment: my table reservation contain date like that 25-nov-18 and the value I get sysdate is 25-nov-18 so there are equal. Am I right ?

Comment: @Saad: whatever tool you're using is only displaying the day-month-year portion of the DATE values you're looking at. But in Oracle all DATE values contain year, month, day, hour, minute, and second - [see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413). Just because all the fields are not displayed does not mean they're absent. And, except at midnight, at least one of the hour, minute, or second fields contains a non-zero value.

Comment: @BobJarvis what should I do ? i try with trunc but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle columns and variables of type DATE have date component (year-month-day) plus time component (hour in 24 hours clock, minutes, seconds).
How you "see" on screen depends of development tool and local configuration of tool.
some tools if time component is midnight (00:00:00) don't display the time component.
Also your country/session region affects how the tool display dates.
The TRUNC function over a value of type DATE without the second parameter gives a value of type DATE whose component time is midnight (00:00:00).

So to compare 2 values of same day use:

```
Trunc(:old.datedep)=trunc(dateres)
```